# Relativity and Reflection

Tags: reflection, relativity

Suppose that you have a hollow pipe of some sort long enough to cover the distance between earth and another planet approximately 4000 light years away. The setup is done is such a way that a room is clearly visible through the hollow pipe in the other planet. If suppose there is a mirror in the room placed right in front of the pipe on the other planet, then if a person gazes through the pipe will he see a reflection of himself or will be not see a mirror at all assuming that he will see what was there 4000 years earlier on the planet?

Comment: Was there a mirror on the planet 4000 years ago?

Comment: Want answers to both if there was a mirror 4000 years ago and if there wasn't a mirror 4000 years ago on the planet.

Comment: Why 4000 light years? Things that far away have to be very bright and very large, if you want to see them with the naked eye. And the pipe makes it even more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume space does not expand inbetween the two planets.

If somebody placed a mirror on both planets 4000 years ago, and constructed the pipe.

If somebody looks into the mirror today, then he will see photons coming from the other planet that have been traveling for 4000 years (since the distance is 4000 light years), so he will see the construction (or the people who constructed the mirror) on the other planet.

If you want to see your own mirrors reflections, you have to look into the mirrors another 4000 years from now (so 8000 years after construction), because the photons have to travel 4000 lightyears twice.

Comment: In other words. Photons are the basic unit of information?

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion yes they are